# Special shadow in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

On the left side of the image below shows what I want to achieve. On the right what Xcode did.

[image: Image 1]

My settings, below.

[image: Image 2]

Is there a way to add the shadow like the picture on top?

Comment: “The image below” shows two different circles. Are you trying to use a shadow to achieve the effect on the left, the effect on the right, or both effects?

Comment: Right both are shadows.

Comment: Reduce shadow radius to zero. And if you don’t want to see the shadow in the top of the circle, you have to supply a solid fill to your shape.